# How to send Xml data and string in JSON form using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am fetching a row from database which is having XML columns as well as string columns. I am able to convert XML data in JSON and then insert it along with other  string data into DataTable and then convert then both to JSON string.
But then the JSON data which i initially got from converting XML that itself is again getting converted which is giving me Wrong data.

```
public string FetchData(int? requestID)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    requestID = 453;
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_GetData]", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;



    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = requestID;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;


    da.Fill(dt);

    //string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
    string id = dt.Rows[0]["RequestId"].ToString();
    string guid = dt.Rows[0]["RequestGuid"].ToString();
    string requestXml = dt.Rows[0]["RequestXml"].ToString();
    string requestDate = dt.Rows[0]["RequestDate"].ToString();
    string responseXml = dt.Rows[0]["ResponseXml"].ToString();
    string responseDate = dt.Rows[0]["ResponseDate"].ToString();
    string documentDetails = dt.Rows[0]["DocumentTypeDetails"].ToString();
    string showRecInfo = dt.Rows[0]["ShowRecordingInfo"].ToString();
    string isOfficeDetailsRequest = dt.Rows[0]["IsOfficeDetailsRequest"].ToString();
    string UserId = dt.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
    string isSaved = dt.Rows[0]["IsSaved"].ToString();
    string name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();

    XmlDocument xmlreq = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocument xmlres = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    // xml.LoadXml(s);
    xmlreq.LoadXml(requestXml);
    xmlres.LoadXml(responseXml);
    xmldoc.LoadXml(documentDetails);


    string reqjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlreq, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
    string resjson= JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlres, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
    string docjson= JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmldoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if(col.ColumnName== "RequestXml")
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, reqjson);
            }
            else if (col.ColumnName == "ResponseXml")
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, resjson);
            }
            else if (col.ColumnName == "DocumentTypeDetails")
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, docjson);
            }
            else
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, serializer.Serialize(dr[col]));
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    con.Close();
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);  
}
```

The Xml data i am getting is coming in this Format.

```html
"RequestId": 453,
        "RequestGuid": "a81b5878-6214-44b4-8888-aab46ce48adf",
        "RequestXml": "{\"App\":\"B\",\"Authentication\":{\"UserID\":\"tb\",\"Password\":\"abc\"},\"TransactionDate\":\"1/27/2001\",\"TransactionCode\":\"6100\",\"Property\":{\"Page\":\"AL005\",\"City\":null,\"County\":null,\"State\":\"AL\",\"EstimatedValue\":\"150000\",\"MortgageAmount\":null,\"OriginalDebtAmount\":null,\"UnpaidPrincipalBalance\":null,\"OriginalMortgageDate\":null,\"StateQuestions\":{\"Q1\":\"0\",\"Q2\":\"0\",\"Q3\":\"0\",\"Q4\":\"1\",\"Q5\":\"0\",\"Q6\":\"0\",\"Q7\":\"0\",\"Q8\":\"0\",\"Q9\":\"0\",\"Q10\":\"0\",\"Q11\":\"0\",\"Q12\":\"0\",\"Q13\":\"0\",\"Q14\":\"0\",\"Q15\":\"0\",\"Q16\":\"0\",\"Q17\":\"0\",\"Q18\":\"0\",\"Q19\":\"0\",\"Q20\":\"0\",\"Q21\":\"0\",\"V1\":\"0\",\"V2\":\"0\",\"V3\":\"0\",\"V4\":\"0\"}},\"NumberOfPages\":{\"Mortgage\":null,\"Deed\":\"1\"},\"Assignment\":{\"Pages\":null,\"NumberOfAssignments\":null},\"Release\":{\"Pages\":null,\"NumberOfReleases\":null},\"DataSource\":\"P\"}",
        "RequestDate": "\/Date(1264562248000)\/",
```

How do i convert everything into one JSON string so that i can use it in my application

Desired Output

```html
"SomeString":{
  "A":"A",
  "B":"B"
}
```

Comment: You can send xml as string property in return object, without conversions.

Comment: @BWA then its giving result in the form of "RequestXml":"\u003cRequest\u003e\u003cApp\u003eB\u003c/App\u003e\u003cAuthentication\u003e\u003cUserID\u003ectiuser\u003c/UserID\tb\u003cPassword\u003eabc\u003c/Password\u003e\u003c/Authentication\u003e\u003cTransactionDate\u003e1/27/2010\u003c/TransactionDate\u003e\u003cTrans/"